# generating bibliography items when using biblatex with WinEdt 6.0 and MikTeX2.9

Tags: biblatex, winedt

I just started using the `biblatex` package, it seems to have nice features for a full control over your citations and bibliography.

However something I miss from using the native BibTeX with WinEdt and MikTeX, is that after execution of the BibTex command, it would generate automatically my bibliography items so that could access them by citation key in the tree view or the gather view of the WinEdt GUI. It would also, whenever I'd type the `\cite{}` command, come up with a popup menu listing those items.

Is there any chance I could get this feature back with the `biblatex` package?

Answer (score 4):

Bibliography items should appear in the project tree if you use `\bibliography`. To get this feature working with `\addbibresource`, you need to add a [WinEdt input directive](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/6766). Open up the options interface (*Options... > Options Interface*) and go to *Navigation > Input Directives*. This will open the `Input.ini` script. After the `\bibliography` directive, add this new entry:

```
  DIRECTIVE="\addbibresource??{??}"
    EXTENSION=".;.bib"
    PATH="%P;%p;%@('BIBINPUTS');"
```

Save and reload the script. Once you rebuild your project tree, the bibliography items should appear.

A menu containing the items should popup when you add braces to `\cite` or any natbib citation command. With biblatex you could simply use the package option setting `natbib=true`. Otherwise this feature can be extended to biblatex citation commands by further modifying WinEdt option scripts. From the options interface go to *Delimiters... > Active Strings*. After the `\cite?{` string in `ActiveStrings.ini` add the following.

```
STRING="\?cite?{}"
  ENABLED=1
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Cite.edt');]"
  DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
  DBL_CLICK_FILTER="TeX"
  DBL_CLICK_ACTION="[IfNum(%c,%x,'<','SwapCaretSelect;');CharRight(2);Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Cite.edt');]"

STRING="\?cite?{?},,"
  ENABLED=1
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Cite-cont.edt');]"

STRING="\?cite?{?,,"
  ENABLED=0
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[Exe('%b\Macros\Active Strings\Cite-sel.edt');]"

STRING="\?cite?{?}"
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[GDIShow;GDISetPage('Bib','%?');]"
  DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
  DBL_CLICK_FILTER="TeX"
  DBL_CLICK_ACTION="[IfNum(%c,%x,'<','SwapCaretSelect;');MatchDelimiter(1,1,1);CharLeft;GDIShow;GDISetPage('Bib','%?');]"

STRING="\?cite?{"
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[Relax;]"
  DBL_CLICK_ENABLED=1
  DBL_CLICK_FILTER="TeX"
  DBL_CLICK_ACTION="[IfNum(%c,%x,'<','SwapCaretSelect;');CharRight;GDIShow;GDISetPage('Bib');]"
```

From the options interface, go to *Navigation > Gather*. In `Gather.ini` add alternatives for the `\cite{?}` and `\cite[?]{?}` items. For example:

```
  ITEM="\cite{?}"
    ALT="\nocite?{?}"
    // NatBib extension
    ALT="\citep{?}"
    ALT="\citet{?}"
    ALT="\citealp{?}"
    ALT="\citealt{?}"
    ALT="\citefullauthor{?}"
    ALT="\citeauthor{?}"
    ALT="\citeyear{?}"
    // biblatex extension
    ALT="\autocite?{?}"
    ALT="\Autocite?{?}"
    ALT="\textcite?{?}"
    ALT="\Textcite?{?}"
    ...
```

Getting the popup feature working with multi-citation commands that generate qualified citation lists (e.g. `\cites[<prenote1>][<postnote1>]{key1}[<prenote2>][<postnote2>]{key2}`), will probably require a new active string macro. I ditched Windows awhile back so I never got around to writing any myself. The existing macros `Cite.edt`, `Cite-cont.edt` and `Cite-sel.edt` provide some examples. These can be found under *Advanced Configuration > Active Strings* from the options interface.

Comment: Thanks Audrey for your reply,

The modification of the Input.ini worked great! and the ActiveString.ini already contained your suggestion.

A weird thing though, is that when trying to get back to the original state by removing the modifications added to the Input.ini file and working with a new project, I still got the bibliography items listed in the tree as well as the pop-up window when using the \cite command.

It doesn't matter much because I don't really want to get back to things not working as I would like; it just seems strange to me (probably due to my poor understanding of WinEdt).

Comment: @Adrien Thanks for the info. Alex must have added the active strings in a more recent build. I'm not sure why you can't revert back to old option settings - I often used to do that in testing ini files. It might take rebuilding your project tree. I hear WinEdt 7 has a GUI for some of the options interface, which might help you manage your settings.